# android intent filter?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm feeling stupid.This is very clear but I can not solve my problem.So excuse me for my question.
My problem is in about intenfilter.This is application tag of my manifest file:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AlakyTestActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="reza"
            android:name=".A2" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="MAIN" />

                <category android:name="LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And this is my button click listener:

```
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.setAction("MAIN");
                intent2.addCategory("LAUNCHER");
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });
```

I think that all things is good but when I run my code and click on `b1`,I get this erroe:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=MAIN cat=[LAUNCHER] }
```

**Edit**:
This is A2:

```
public class A2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }


}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You do not have an activity named `A2`; as in `public class A2 extends Activity{`.... I suggest you read up a bit more about Android development to get comfortable first.

Comment: Put a period in front of the name `A2` like this...`android:name=".A2"`. In saying that though, although you can use any names in your own package `intnet-filter` enteries for your action and category, using `MAIN` and `Launcher` is a little confusing - use something more representative of what the `A2` activity does.

Comment: @t0mm13b Ok,thank you I add my `A2` to my question.

Comment: @Squonk Thank you ,I add `.` in front of 'A2' but it does not work.Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @StudentStudent : Is the `A2` activity in the same package as the `AlakyTestActivity`?

Comment: @Squonk yes.My project has only one pakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the android:name of the second activity to the (package name).(the class)
for example, lets say the second activity class is 'com.my.app.reza' you should add you the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".reza" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.my.app.REZA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFUALT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and you should start the activity like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.app.REZA");
startActivity(intent);
```

NOTE that it isn't the best way to do it, you shouldn't mess to much with package name I'd recommend you to do it the following way:

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".reza" />
```

and start it like that:

```
startActivity(new Intent( this.getContext() , reza.class );
```

Comment: I have to use intent-filter in my project,instead of explicit intents.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like that:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,A2.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```

`android:name=".A2"` ,you must have `"A2"` activity class implement!

Modify to `android:name=".A2"`, not `android:name="A2"`!

Comment: I have to use `intent-filter` in my project,instead of explicit intents.

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.blacky.basictutorial.TutorialTwo" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Try to use this in your second activity and call by the following code:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.blacky.basictutorial.TutorialTwo"));
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify category if you just need to call `A2` inside your app. And you should set an unique action name, for example it can be a hash string:

```
...
Intent intent2 = new Intent("a202bfa923069ee8e119205e3468ee131ceafda37");
startActivity(intent2);
```

Note that action name uses same rule as package name.